# nativescript-audio recording not recognized in html sound element

Tags: android, html, audio, nativescript

I have successfully implemented recording `mp3` with the `nativescript-audio` plugin.

I send the mp3 to the ASP server and I can play these files with MediaPlayer.

Next I have successfully implemented the html SOUND element that plays mp3 files from said server.

The problem is, the mp3 files that I recorded and sent from the android (NativeScript) are NOT recognised as valid mp3 by the HTML SOUND element.....

I tried some of the format and audio decoder settings but didn't get any results….
 anyone have an idea for preferably this combination, or another plugin for NativeScript or a way of playing these files on the website (client side playback) ???

Answer (score 0):

I needed to convert .caf files (created with the audio-plugin on iOS). I found that 
i could use ffmpeg.exe to convert the .caf to mp3 in my ASP.NET website. (code below).
the converted file could be played using the HTML SOUND element. So i tried converting the mp3 files that were created by the nativescrip-audio plugin, using the same converter... and .. Voila ! it works like a charm too....

```
string outPath = path.Replace(".caf", ".mp3");
string ConverterPath =httpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/HttpHandlers/ffmpeg.exe");
//myffmpeg.exe is in the folder :  ~/HttpHandlers  
string commandLine = string.Format("-i {0} {1}", tmpPath, outPath);
process convertor = Process.Start(ConverterPath, commandLine);
convertor.WaitForExit();           
//delete temp file
fi = new FileInfo(tmpPath);
if (fi.Exists)
{
    fi.Delete();
}
```